# Nexus 5 stuck on boot loop after restarting while upgrading the OS

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, nexus-5, boot-loop, fastboot

Last week, I received an update on my Nexus 5 for Lollipop 5.0.1. Version 5.0 was working fine, so I decided to just update. However, a few hours after updating, my phone started to lag and freeze, so I decided to restart. My phone is now stuck in a boot loop and I can't fix it. I don't know what to do. I cant get pass the start up animation no matter what I do.

I've tried the fast boot commands and keep getting the error

> FAILED < remote: flash write failure >

I've tried the `flash-all.bat` file, but the lock state goes back to LOCKED when it reboots the device and I get the error

> not supported on lock device

I can unlock the device when I type `fastboot oem unlock`, but if the device is restarted it goes back to LOCKED.

I've tried recovery mode and I see the below statements:

```
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /ache/recovery/log
E:Can't open /ache/recovery/log
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /ache/recovery/last_log
E:Can't open /ache/recovery/last_log
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /ache/recovery/last_install
E:Can't open /ache/recovery/last_install
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
```

I've tried wipe data/factory reset

```
--Wiping data...
Formatting /data...
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
Formatting /cache...
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /ache/recovery/log
E:Can't open /ache/recovery/log
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /ache/recovery/last_log
E:Can't open /ache/recovery/last_log
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /ache/recovery/last_install
E:Can't open /ache/recovery/last_install
Data wipe complete
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /ache/recovery/log
E:Can't open /ache/recovery/log
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /ache/recovery/last_log
E:Can't open /ache/recovery/last_log
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /ache/recovery/last_install
E:Can't open /ache/recovery/last_install
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
```

and still nothing

I've tried the `adb sideload` and haven't gotten anywhere, it's not recognizing the phone in recovery mode.

I've even tried `fastboot erase userdata` but nothing happened.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Was this "stock" Android?